# Calling HttpClient using Existing session

Tags: c#, .net, session, frameworks, httpclient

I am trying to call HttpClient's methods Getasync and Postasync to call another site that uses the same Single sign-on authentication. Being an async call it doesn't recognize single sign-on and redirects to the login page.

I want to pass my current session to that site so it with authenticate me automatically and give me the requested page/content via response.

I tried with cookie container passing with HttpClient but somehow it didn't work. I am trying this because I want to avoid currently used iframe in the solution that opens requested a page in an iframe. Instead of that I am calling HttpClient and getting a response back so CORS errors will be avoided(in current iframe solution).

Comment: Have you considered Selenium?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But scenario is I am already logged in my application and accessing second application via WebClient  (Its wrong way to use it like web service) hence I want to pass my current session to that app so it will automatically login  in second app. I previously used iframe to open second app now want to discard iframe plus opening new window is avoided due to default popup blocker in many browsers.